# How to use MySQL with Ubuntu ‘C’?

Tags: mysql, c

I am using Ubuntu Linux 20.04.2 and MySQL 8.0.30 but when I try to compile using a Linux Terminal command like:
gcc -o program program.c ‘mysql_config —libs’
I get a message like:
“Error: mysql. . No such file or directory”

It appears that gcc doesn’t recognize the directory where the ‘Include’ ( .h ) files are located.
That is: ‘/usr/include/mysql’.
I have tried several variations of the gcc command without success. There is probably a simple solution and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The [mysql_config manual](https://manpages.org/mysql_config) has an example of the exact commands needed.

Comment: show a minimal program.c that produces the problem.

Comment: if you haven't already, install the library/headers: `sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev`

Answer (score 0):

It's `$(pkg-config --libs --cflags mysql...)`, replace the **mysql...** with the name of library.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who answered my question. What seems to have solved the problem, is adding the -I option to the gcc command. I used:
$ gcc -o progrm -I /usr/include/mysql program.c